# How can I change the background color for only the rows that are "true"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I change the background color for only the rows that were (true) as per `function checkDate(row)` on the originating sheet "Pasco"? Is this possible?

A little bit about the script:

A date range is inputted through `function getDateRange()`, all rows in sheet "Pasco" is checked for if they meet that date range through `function checkDate(row)`. If it does meet the date range (true), `function filterRows()` essentially filters the rows from "Pasco" sheet, and moves them over to another sheet "Copy of Pasco".

Another way of asking my question, how can I get a range of all the rows that were "true" in sheet "Pasco". If "Pasco" wasn't sorted by date, this could mean multiple ranges, right? Once I have a range I'd be able to change background easy.

If you are to test the script, please create two sheets, 'Pasco' and 'Copy of Pasco'. In 'Pasco' Starting from row 2, place some dates down column I (column 8). To see the filtering in action. 'Copy of Pasco' will be deleted/created on each run.

Thank you for your time =)

```
var globalStartDate;
var globalEndDate;

function getDateRange(){

  var startui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var startprompt = startui.prompt('Start Date', 'Enter a date in m/d/y format', startui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var startdate = new Date(startprompt.getResponseText());
  var startdatemilliseconds = startdate.getTime();
  Logger.log(startdate);
  Logger.log(startdatemilliseconds);
  globalStartDate  = startdatemilliseconds;

  var endui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var endprompt = endui.prompt('End Date', 'Enter a date in m/d/y format', endui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var enddate = new Date(endprompt.getResponseText());
  var enddatemilliseconds = enddate.getTime();
  Logger.log(enddate);
  Logger.log(enddatemilliseconds);
  globalEndDate  = enddatemilliseconds;
}

function checkDate(row) {

  Logger.log(row[8].getTime() <= globalEndDate && row[8].getTime() >= globalStartDate);
  return (row[8].getTime() <= globalEndDate && row[8].getTime() >= globalStartDate);  // Check column H
}

function filterRows() {

  var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Pasco');
  var sheetdelete = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Pasco');

  Spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheetdelete);
  Spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet1);
  Spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();

  var headers = 1; // # rows to skip
  var sheet2 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Pasco');
  var range = sheet1.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var headerData = data.splice(0,headers); // Skip header rows
  getDateRange();
  var filteredData = data.filter( checkDate );
  var outputData = headerData.concat(filteredData);  // Put headers back
  Logger.log(filteredData)

  sheet2.clearContents();  // Clear content, keep format

  // Save filtered values
  sheet2.getRange(1, 1, outputData.length, outputData[0].length).setValues(outputData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I don't have time to read through your code and give you a complete answer but you could just add a loop to go through the sheet and set the background colour of each row with 'true'.

In my script below I assume 'true' is in column A.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var lastCol = sheet.getMaxColumns();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++){
  if(data[i][0] == true){
  sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, lastCol).setBackground('Yellow');
   }
  }
 }
```

**EDIT**

Insert this code after you call `getDateRange()` in the filter rows function.

```
  var lastCol = sheet1.getMaxColumns(); 

  for(var i = headers; i < data.length ; i++){ 
  if(data[i][8].getTime() <= globalEndDate && data[i][8].getTime() >= globalStartDate){ 
  sheet1.getRange(i, 1, 1, lastCol).setBackground('Yellow'); 
    } 
   }
```

Your filter rows function should now look like this:

```
function filterRows() {

  var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Pasco');
  var sheetdelete = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Pasco');

  Spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheetdelete);
  Spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet1);
  Spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();

  var headers = 1; // # rows to skip
  var sheet2 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Pasco');
  var range = sheet1.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var headerData = data.splice(0,headers); // Skip header rows
  getDateRange();

  var lastCol = sheet1.getMaxColumns(); 
  for(var i = headers; i < data.length ; i++){ 
  if(data[i][8].getTime() <= globalEndDate && data[i][8].getTime() >= globalStartDate){ 
  sheet1.getRange(i + headers, 1, 1, lastCol).setBackground('Yellow'); 
    } 
   } 

  var filteredData = data.filter( checkDate );
  var outputData = headerData.concat(filteredData);  // Put headers back
  Logger.log(filteredData)

  sheet2.clearContents();  // Clear content, keep format

  // Save filtered values
  sheet2.getRange(1, 1, outputData.length, outputData[0].length).setValues(outputData);
}
```

Comment: I really wish you had the time to read through, i think your answer has the potential to solve my problem, if you are able to later, could you please read through and tweak your code please.

Comment: Done please see above.. Is this what you require?

Comment: We are much closer now! Problem is that it is changing the background to rows it shouldn't be, rows that should be failing the IF statement in your code. In one test of mine, it actually changed the header row (row 1) as well. The date it should be checking is in column I. Not sure if you're able to test the script as a whole, just create the necessary sheets, and put dates in place. I really appreciate your help! =)

Comment: Just thought I'd add my code is working as needed. Can we utilize function checkDate(row) in your code? If the row passes that test, it's background changes? I'm not very expierenced, but in your code you are referencing range.getValues, how is it supposed to know what row it's on? Also unsure of your reference of var headers. Cheers =) @JamesDonnellan

Comment: Of course ir was as easy as a missing "+2". Thank you again for all your help. `sheet1.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, lastCol).setBackground('Yellow');`

Comment: I must admit, I didn't test the code.. In relation to your comments above-

Referencing `var data = range.getValues()`; - in my loop I then use `data[i][8]` the [8] reperesents the 8th position (i.e. column 8) in array [i].

Comment: My reference to `var headers` - you have created this reference which made me this that you may at some point change the number of header rows. By using this reference in my loop if you do change the number of header rows the code in the loop does not need to be updated.  

If you change `sheet1.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, lastCol).setBackground('Yellow');`   to   `sheet1.getRange(i + headers, 1, 1, lastCol).setBackground('Yellow');` it should work as expected.

Comment: i + headers (headers = 1) wasn't working for me either, not a 100% sure, but I think it's due to the data.splice. It needed to be +2 for some reason, we got there in the end. Cheers!

Comment: 'We got there in the end' lol that is the most important thing!!